# Laravel PHP: Using Filters with Routes to grant admin access only

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to protect some of my web pages by only allowing administrators to access them.  I've been trying to use a filter to protect these pages but it isn't working as intended.  For instance, if a user tries to enter an admin URL into their web browser, the browser still grants the unauthorized user access.

EDIT: Made changes to my code below so that the admin pages are only accessed after successfully logging in.

**Routes.php:**

```
 // All users have access to this home page

 Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', function()
{
// Default home page 
return View::make('index');
}
]);

//Admin access only

Route::get('admin/index', ['before' => 'auth',function()
{
      //Only allow admin access to this page       
      return View::make('admin_index');
}
]);
```

**filters.php (The default filters.php file):**

```
/* Default 'filters.php' is fine.  */

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
   if (Auth::guest())
   {
       if (Request::ajax())
       {
         return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
       }
       else
       {
        return Redirect::guest('login');
       }
   }
});
```

**Controller (SesssionsController.php):**

```
public function index()
{
    return View::make('sessions.index');
}

/* 
Show the form for creating a new resource 
*/

public function create()
{
    return View::make('sessions.create');
}

public function store()
{

// validate

$input = Input::all();

$attempt = Auth::attempt([
    'email'=> $input['email'],
    'password' => $input['password']
    ]);

// If authentication passes, take the user back to the homepage (For Now)

/* EDIT: Changed 'Redirect::intended(admin/index)' to 'Redirect::to('admin/index')... since that was giving me problems */

if ($attempt) return Redirect::to('admin/index')->with('flash_message', 'Welcome ' . $input['email']. ', you are logged in!');

return Redirect::back()->with('flash_message', 'Invalid credentials.')->withInput();

}
```

After making these changes, I ran 'php artisan dump-autoload' in order for the changes in my Controller to take effect and now my 'admin/index' page  can only be accessed after successfully logging in.

Hope this information helps people out!

Comment: Once your filter is called `Auth` and the other time `auth`

Comment: After changing 'Auth' to 'auth', it's still producing the same problem.

Comment: If you put `dd('test')` at the beginning of your filter function, does it show "test" when accessing `admin/index`?

Comment: Yes it does lukasgeiter.

Comment: Hmm and if you put it inside the `Auth::guest()` if statement?

Comment: I'm actually trying a couple of experiments right now, one of them actually worked for me lol.  I'll keep you posted lukasgeiter.

Comment: Ok I think I've found a solution and I'm going to edit my answer above so that people with similar problems will know what to do!